# How do I apply a filter, but only to a part of a stacked bar in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have the following order data:

[image]

for every hour, the blue part shows the amount of invalid orders, while the orange part indicates valid orders. I have created a filter to filter orders with prices greater than 300 USD, but I want to apply the filter to valid orders only .I cannot figure out how to do that, I want each of the stacked bars to have three pieces: invalid orders, valid orders below 300 usd and valid orders above 300 usd.

An alternative would be to have three bars (total order amount, valid order count,valid and gretaer than 300 USD count) grouped for every hour, Which, once again, I cannot figure out how to do it. Please Help me out.

Clarification: original data looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer properly when I can't see Rows, Columns and the Marks Card, but can create a calculated field that is something like:

if [Order Total] >= 300 then 1 end

and another

if [Order Total] < 300 then 1 end

and use both of these instead of your orange bar (is that COUNT(Order) ?) that you have now.

Comment: Clarification added. The orange and blue bar represents 1 and 0 of  a parameter called "sale_ord_valid_flag" in the original data. So I am not exactly sure about how to replace only the orange bar... And amount of order is calculated by counting sale_ord_id.

Comment: So do you have 2 calculated fields now ? one for blue and one for orange ? Or have you just put sale_ord_valid_flag on Color ?

Comment: Yes I just put sale_ord_valid_flag on Color